# How to fetch specific field value from the json response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, google-bigquery, python-requests

How to fetch and print the Invoice url and merchant_name from the json response ? in Python

### Here is my payload

```
import requests
import csv
from google.colab import files


url = "https://api.vdit.co/v2/invoices"

payload = "{\n\t\"external_id\": \"invoice-1597479693\",\n\t\"amount\": 3800000,\n\t\"payer_email\": \"customer@domain.com\",\n\t\"description\": \"Invoice Demo #1234\"\n}"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic sfdfsdfsdfdsfds==',
  'Cookie': 'visid_incap_2182539=9txMzsXTSfuzBolYeHI2Ui6hLl4AAAAAQUIPAAAAAABantpi5VKWQTh30yiNhG8y; nlbi_2182539=H15dNsiPqheQ/JGAjjCKbQAAAAAuILnoaVKZa2DtKg9G+o7E; incap_ses_1130_2182539=pdnQReH84gIVq2yWKJGuDz2aN18AAAAABIuVf37dWMch3rIN+1PZJg=='
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
print(response.text)
```

---

Response

```
"id":"5f38a9e14b73f4203a87465b","external_id":"invoice-1597479693","user_id":"5da7afcf5bf71e7c19d0a722","status":"PENDING","merchant_name":"PT Evi Asia Tenggara","merchant_profile_picture_url":"https://du8nwjtfkinx.cloudfront.net/vdit.png","amount":3800000,"payer_email":"customer@domain.com","description":"Invoice Demo #1234","expiry_date":"2020-08-17T03:37:05.746Z","invoice_url":"https://invoice-staging.vdit.co/web/invoices/5f38a9e14b73f4203a87465b","available_banks":[{"bank_code":"MANDIRI","collection_type":"POOL","bank_account_number":"8860848092927","transfer_amount":3800000,"bank_branch":"Virtual Account","account_holder_name":"PT ABC ASIA TENGGARA","identity_amount":0},{"bank_code":"BRI","collection_type":"POOL","bank_account_number":"2621556085816","transfer_amount":3800000,"bank_branch":"Virtual Account","account_holder_name":"PT ABV ASIA TENGGARA","identity_amount":0},{"bank_code":"BNI","collection_type":"POOL","bank_account_number":"880855854767","transfer_amount":3800000,"bank_branch":"Virtual Account","account_holder_name":"PT ABC ASIA TENGGARA","identity_amount":0},{"bank_code":"PERMATA","collection_type":"POOL","bank_account_number":"821457925493","transfer_amount":3800000,"bank_branch":"Virtual Account","account_holder_name":"PT  ASIA TENGGARA","identity_amount":0},{"bank_code":"BCA","collection_type":"POOL","bank_account_number":"1076620926923","transfer_amount":3800000,"bank_branch":"Virtual Account","account_holder_name":"PT ABC ASIA TENGGARA","identity_amount":0}],"available_ewallets":[],"should_exclude_credit_card":false,"should_send_email":false,"created":"2020-08-16T03:37:05.804Z","updated":"2020-08-16T03:37:05.804Z","currency":"IDR"}
JSON received:
```

How to fetch and print the Invoice url and merchant_name from the json response ? in Python

I want result to be like this, Please guide me

> Invoice Url :
> "https://invoice-staging.vdit.co/web/invoices/5f38a9e14b73f4203a87465b"
> merchant_name : PT ABC ASIA TENGGARA

Thanks in Advance

Comment: ``response.json()`` would return dict then access by key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work

```
resp = response.json()
invoice_url = resp['invoice_url']
merchant_name = resp['merchant_name']
print(invoice_url, marchant_name)
```